# How to rename files in hdfs from spark more efficiently?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I have 450K JSONs, and I want to rename them in hdfs based on certain rules. For the sake of simplicity I just add a suffix `.finished` to each of them.
A managed to do this, with the following code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

val hdfs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
val files = hdfs.listStatus(new Path(pathToJson))
val originalPath = files.map(_.getPath())

for(i <- originalPath.indices)
{
   hdfs.rename(originalPath(i), originalPath(i).suffix(".finished"))
}
```

But it takes 12 minutes to rename all of them. Is there a way to make it faster? (Perhaps parallelize)
I use spark 1.6.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

originalpath.par.foreach(  e  =>   hdfs.rename(e,e.suffix("finish")))

Comment: And how would you do this if you have two arrays, for instance: `originalPath` and `newPath`? So I want to apply the rename function for two arrays. I tried something with zip and your solution, but it's not working.

Comment: I figured out how to do it in this case, and now it takes only approx 5 minutes. I think the difference was made by the `par` function.