# Serialization issue while renaming HDFS File using scala Spark in parallel

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to rename HDFS Files in parallel using spark. But I am getting serialization exception, I have mention the exception after my code.
I am getting this issue while using spark.sparkContext.parallelize. Also I am able to rename all the files, when doing it in a loop.

```
  def renameHdfsToS3(spark : SparkSession, hdfsFolder :String, outputFileName:String,
                     renameFunction: (String,String) => String, bktOutput:String, folderOutput:String, kmsKey:String): Boolean = {
    try {
      val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
      val path = new Path(hdfsFolder)
      val files = fs.listStatus(path)
        .filter(fs => fs.isFile)

      val parallelRename=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(files).map(
        f=>{
          parallelRenameHdfs(fs,outputFileName,renamePartFileWithTS,f)
        }
      )
      val hdfsTopLevelPath=fs.getWorkingDirectory()+"/"+hdfsFolder
      return true
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return false
      }
    }
  }
```

Below is the exception I am getting

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:340)

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem, value: org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem@1d96d872)
    - field (class:         at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
```

Comment: Not sure of the answer but it does not strike me as the correct approach.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430588/how-to-rename-files-in-hdfs-from-spark-more-efficiently

Comment: @thebluephantom Hi I have checked that post, there the files are renamed serially ..but I am looking for an approach where I can rename all the files in parallel.

Comment: Look at the answer. Note the .par !!!

Comment: Sorry didnt release it lately .. Thanks !

Comment: no problem, u r in the no now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is incorrect as sc.parallelize is for consuming data via RDDs. You need to be working at the operating system level. Many such posts exist.

Something like this should suffice blending it with your own logic, note par which allows parallel processing, e.g.:

```
originalpath.par.foreach( e => hdfs.rename(e,e.suffix("finish")))
```

You need to check how parallelism is defined with .par. Look here https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html